# How to dump postgresql database on ubuntu?

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu

Now i try to backup postgresql database by using python.

```
import gzip
from sh import pg_dump

def dump_database():
    with gzip.open('ticketing.sql', 'wb') as f:
        pg_dump('-h', 'localhost', '-U', 'postgres', 'mydatabase', _out=f)
dump_database()
```

which work normally on my macbook but when i try to run this code on ubuntu server, it error like this.

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "mydatabase" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

So why it not working on ubuntu server and how to fix that.

Assume if my password = `password123`

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable in your python script for PGPASSWORD as:-

```
import os
os.environ['PGPASSWORD'] = 'password123'
```

Or you can create a .pgpass file in the home directory of the account that pg_dump will run as Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: thank you for response but after i set the password env i got the another error like this `pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "mydatabase" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Comment: Try running the script as posgres user by using `sudo su postgres`

Comment: The error indicates you are using the wrong password. The correct user is being specified, ```failed for user "postgres```, so you don't need to sudo.  Best guess is the wrong environment is being picked up or the password being set is incorrect.